# Smooth transitions when changing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website change pages smoothly (between Home, About us, etc).
Something like this: https://5scontent.com/ when you navigate to WORK or ABOUT.

I'm using plain html, css and vanilla Javascript because it's a very simple page.

At first, I tried having all the elements hidden and making them appear using Javascript. But it makes the page load very long because we have lots of images.

What would be the recommended way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: Try adding `<img loading=lazy>`

Comment: Your approach is good for a very simple page, the main problem here is the images load. You could set a data-url property instead of url and set that value to the url only when the active page is displayed

Comment: take a look at this https://barba.js.org/ please.

Comment: and use this to minimize your images' size https://squoosh.app/